# Public Property Array Setting Values

Tags: json, vb.net

I am using VB2010 and I want to without error or usigg Try, to check if a public property array index is existent. So, I am deserializing json data that looks like this:

```
{
  "Title": "The Terminator",
  "Year": "1984",
  "Rated": "R",
  "Released": "26 Oct 1984",
  "Runtime": "107 min",
  "Genre": "Action, Sci-Fi",
  "Director": "James Cameron",
  "Writer": "James Cameron, Gale Anne Hurd, William Wisher (additional dialogue)",
  "Actors": "Arnold Schwarzenegger, Michael Biehn, Linda Hamilton, Paul Winfield",
  "Plot": "A seemingly indestructible robot is sent from 2029 to 1984 to assassinate a young waitress, whose unborn son will lead humanity in a war against sentient machines, while a human soldier from the same war is sent to protect her at all costs.",
  "Language": "English, Spanish",
  "Country": "UK, USA",
  "Awards": "6 wins & 6 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTViNzMxZjEtZGEwNy00MDNiLWIzNGQtZDY2MjQ1OWViZjFmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "8.0/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "100%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "84/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "84",
  "imdbRating": "8.0",
  "imdbVotes": "731,313",
  "imdbID": "tt0088247",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "03 Sep 1997",
  "BoxOffice": "N/A",
  "Production": "Orion Pictures Corporation",
  "Website": "http://www.terminator1.com/",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

However, not all movies return the "Ratings" array. So, I want to be able to still set the array as Source imdb, rotten tomatoes, and metacritic and those Values as "N/A" if they don't exist. I wish the api would just return it as N/A it would be so much easier.

Here's my class for Ratings:

```
Public Class Ratings
    Public Property Source As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Then my other class that returns the other values from the "Search" Array and it returns a good handful of different strings so I'll just skip to where I do ratings..

```
Public Class Results
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Year As String
    'bunch more public property strings... 
    Public Property Rating As Ratings() 
End Class
```

Now my form on load im just testing it out and of course I get an index out of bounds error if I try to set it manually or read a specific index because if the array isn't there, then the array  indexes are non existent.

```
Imports System.Net 
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Dim Site As New WebClient() 
Dim JSS As JavascriptSerializer = New JavascriptSerializer() 
Dim strData As String = Site.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Terma&apikey=apikeygoeshere
Dim Movie As Results = JSS. Deserializs(Of Results) (strData)
```

And this is where I'm now stuck. I'm not sure what to do here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what do you want to, please paraphrase.

Comment: OK, I have a public class which is an array and each index has a property : Source Strinng, Value String. However, not every movie contains that Rating array. If the array is not in the json data deserialize or the array does not contain index #1 or #2 then I want to set the Value String of that class to be N/A.

Comment: {"Title":"Terma ta difraga","Year":"1962","Rated":"N/A","Released":"N/A","Runtime":"85 min","Genre":"Comedy","Director":"Sakis Tsolakakis","Writer":"Ilias Bakopoulos","Actors":"Vasilis Avlonitis, Pari Leventi, Nikos Rizos, Giorgos Tsitsopoulos","Plot":"N/A","Language":"Greek","Country":"Greece","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"N/A","Ratings":[],"Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"N/A","imdbVotes":"N/A","imdbID":"tt0200204","Type":"movie","DVD":"N/A","BoxOffice":"N/A","Production":"N/A","Website":"N/A","Response":"True"}

Comment: Ok so, you want to insert an array of stuff if it doesn't exist in JSON you get, if I understood right. I don't think there is a point in adding it to JSON as you could simply send it the code that needs it more easily, but without knowing more details of what you do I can't answer on it.

Comment: No, I am displaying these onto another form. If i try to read index 0, 1, and 2 (It doesn't exceed index #2) then it will throw an exception. I know I could try to read it with Try and then set the label's value to N/A in the exception but I am wondering if there's a shorter way of doing it? I did find a longer way of doing it without Try.

Comment: How about check if it is nothing "If Not res.Rating Is Nothing Then " and then get the number of rating values "Dim vals As Integer = res.Rating.GetUpperBound(0)"?

Comment: Yes, but how can i set the indexes that aren't there? Some do return an array of just one index, two indexes, and some return all three indexes. How would I set the new one? Array.Resize inside each if statement of checking upper bound?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what I did. Sorry, I am new here, and I wanted to just add a comment with my code but it's too long. However, if anyone knows a shorter way of doing this, please let me know.

```
Dim jss As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim Site As New WebClient()
    Dim strData As String = Site.DownloadString("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Terminator&y=1984&apikey=745dfb00")
    Dim mvMovie As Results = New Results

    mvMovie = jss.Deserialize(Of Results)(strData)

If mvMovie.Response = "True" Then
        Dim imdbRatings As Ratings = New Ratings
        Dim rtRatings As Ratings = New Ratings
        Dim mtRatings As Ratings = New Ratings
        Dim imdbSource As String = "Internet Movie Database"
        Dim imdbValue As String = "N/A"
        Dim rtSource As String = "Rotten Tomatoes"
        Dim rtValue As String = "N/A"
        Dim mtSource As String = "Metacritic"
        Dim mtValue As String = "N/A"
        If mvMovie.Ratings.GetUpperBound(0) = -1 Then
            Array.Resize(mvMovie.Ratings, 3)
            imdbRatings.Source = imdbSource
            imdbRatings.Value = imdbValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(0) = imdbRatings
            rtRatings.Source = rtSource
            rtRatings.Value = rtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(1) = rtRatings
            mtRatings.Source = mtSource
            mtRatings.Value = mtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(2) = mtRatings
        ElseIf mvMovie.Ratings.GetUpperBound(0) = 0 Then
            Array.Resize(mvMovie.Ratings, 3)
            rtRatings.Source = rtSource
            rtRatings.Value = rtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(1) = rtRatings
            mtRatings.Source = mtSource
            mtRatings.Value = mtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(2) = mtRatings

        ElseIf mvMovie.Ratings.GetUpperBound(0) = 1 AndAlso mvMovie.Ratings(1).Source = "Rotten Tomatoes" Then
            Array.Resize(mvMovie.Ratings, 3)
            mtRatings.Source = mtSource
            mtRatings.Value = mtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(2) = mtRatings
        ElseIf mvMovie.Ratings.GetUpperBound(0) = 1 AndAlso mvMovie.Ratings(1).Source = "Metacritic" Then
            Array.Resize(mvMovie.Ratings, 3)
            rtRatings.Source = rtSource
            rtRatings.Value = rtValue
            mvMovie.Ratings(2) = mvMovie.Ratings(1)
            mvMovie.Ratings(1) = rtRatings
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: It might be possible to use a loop to make it shorter, but I wouldn't worry about it unless you find yourself coming back to this to add more potential sources (which, based on the ones you're showing, I wouldn't expect you will need to do).

Comment: Posting your own answer is acceptable on Stack Overflow. As a matter of fact, you can come back and accept your own answer to signal the readers that follow that the question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I completed the project and am NOW trying the movie database dot org. Am stuck on discovering movies between two certain dates.